# Google reCaptcha errors layering

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, frontend, recaptcha

I'm getting default warning in reCaptcha (This reCaptcha is for...) and when I'm getting another warning they are layering.
Is exist a proppert way to move one of them to the bottom or hide "This reCaptcha is..."?
I've tried to hide it with using css and js, but errors inside Iframe so idk
[image]